# php/sql with json output

Tags: php, sql, json, pdo

I would like to create a json from my database's datas and the json output is like this:

```
`[{"id":"1","0":"1","nom":"test","1":"test","prenom":"john","2":"john","societe":"","3":"","mail":"johntest@gmail.com","4":"johntest@gmail.com","type":"creatif","5":"creatif","url":"johntest","6":"johntest"}]`
```

My php code to doing so is :

```
$stock = array();
$sql = $bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM user");
if ($sql->execute())
{
    while ($row = $sql->fetch())
    $stock[] = $row;
}
print json_encode($stock);
```

My problem here is that everything is doubled, I have a first data with the good property like `"nom":"test"` and then I have a thing out of nowhere `"1":"test"`.

How can I get rid of this second thing?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) in the `fetch()` call:

```
while ($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
```

PDO defaults to `PDO::FETCH_BOTH` which returns both the associative array and the numerical keyed array.

Comment: Thank you guys for your hall it works very well ! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `$sql->fetch()` pass FETCH_ASSOC because default it will use `PDO::FETCH_BOTH`,

```
$sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Read *[PDOStatement::fetch](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)* for more details.